# Value can not be Zero after Pressing Cross button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calculator

all digits clear when pressing the cross button except the last digit

[image: all digits clear when pressing the cross button except the last digit]

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you delete the last digit, `myvalue.text` is equal to an empty string. `double.parse` will throw an error (here it will be silently discarded) and your price is then not assigned, that's why it will display the last digit entered.

To fix it easily, you can replace

```
price = double.parse(myvalue.text);
```

by

```
price = double.tryParse(myvalue.text) ?? 0;
```

This way the empty string will be automatically converted to 0.

Comment: Thanks but it's not work

Comment: Can you show your code modified?